# possible to share strings.xml between apps with the same sharedUserId?

Tags: java, android, android-xml, android-context

I know that it is possible to share SharedPreferences (using the following) when the two apps have the same sharedUserId:

```
Context secondApp = createPackageContext("com.example.secondapp", 0);
SharedPreferences secondAppPreferences = secondApp.getSharedPreferences("name_of_shared_preferences_file", 0);
```

but is it at all possible to share strings from the "strings.xml" file so that i can get a string-array from the second app's stings.xml??

i have tried:

```
secondApp.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.name_of_arr);
```

but it throws an error (array cannot be resolved or is not a field) on "array" in "R.array.name_of_arr"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to share "data" (files, preferences, exposed data) between Android applications, but not built in Resources (i.e. the stuff mapped through `R`). These Resources are all private per application.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible to share strings or any other data between two different applications.

Comment: Any other data? but it is possible to share files, preferences, and i think, databases between applications with the same android:sharedUserId

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is ten years old, but since the accepted answer is incorrect at this point in time, I'm adding an answer.

If the two apps have the same `sharedUserId` and signed with the same certificate then it's possible to

```
fun Context?.getSettingsContext() = this?.createPackageContext("com.android.settings", Context.CONTEXT_RESTRICTED)
```

to get the context (from in this case native settings), and then

```
with(settingsContext.resources) {
        val resId = getIdentifier("accessibility_screen_magnification_gestures_title", "string", "com.android.settings")
        Log.d(TAG, "titleId: ${getString(resId)}")
}
```

also mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16270487/630833) response.