# How to install content in a app with other app

Tags: java, android, eclipse

My question is simple, as in other operating systems like Windows, you can install a program specific content, such as images in the directory of another program so he can have it available for use.

I have understood that Android is based on Linux, and the app can not communicate directly with other.

So i was wondering if it is possible to do this, and if possible what steps should I consider.

To understand that I mean an example would be an app that you install emoticons in whatsapp for example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is a third answer.

If you're the same author for both apps, it's possible if you assign the same sharedUserId in the manifest of both apps and if you sign those two apps with the same key.

This way, both those apps will be treated as one by the system.

See this answer on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16270487/320111

Comment: Then it is theoretically possible to create an app that you install emoticons on whatsapp, if I use the same sharedUserId and sign by the same certificate, in my example

Comment: Actually, if you only want to insert emoticons into Whatsapp, you might want to see if Whatsapp has any api you can use, or you may just want to create your own custom keyboard instead (which can work on all apps, not just Whatsapp).

Comment: See also: https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/iphone/23559013 and https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI

Answer (score 1):

The File dir of an android app is strictly private and only accessable for that app. Even if you could access it on a rooted phone or through some other way, the emoticons for WhatsApp are contained in the Application package. If you want different emoticons for Whatsapp, you will have to decompile, exchange the emoticons, recompile and sign the WhatsApp apk file. This isn't worth the effort, since you could only exchange existing emoticons and it would only be different for you. (I know because i tried myself) Here is a [tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/androidbyyorzua/home/tutorials/how-to-decompile-recompile-sign-whatsapp-apk).

Answer (score 1):

You can't "install content" on another app, but you can [share content providers](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk_content-providers--mobile-5549).

Comment: ok i get it, so if the firts app dont share his contetnt providers, the second app can not communicate