# Communication between two hybrid application using JSONSTORE

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore, worklight-security

Is it possible that one hybrid application can use Jsonstore data of another hybrid application? Both applications are worklight hybrid application.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.

Each JSONStore is stored in the specific's application sandbox and as such it is not possible to retrieve information from a JSONStore that is not located in the specific application sandbox.

Comment: In case of Android, What if Both application have same android:sharedUserId. For the same, sqlite allows sharing.
Shared UserID -->
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16269956/two-app-with-shared-userid

Comment: I am not sure. Please explain your scenario and what are you expecting/what is happening.

Comment: No, it won't work with sharedUserId because it is not programmed to do so.