# Share files between two apps using internal storage

Tags: android

I have two app which use the same package of images. The size of images is 50 Mb. I would like to use these images in both apps but download it only in the internal storage of one of them. Is possible to do this?
I know that I can solve this downloading the images in sd card, but in this case I need to download it in internal storage.

Comment: Yes that is possible.

Comment: @greenapps Could you be more specific?

Comment: Please post your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you own both applications, the simplest (and secure) solution is probably to declare 
 a [sharedUserId](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#uid) :

> If this attribute is set to the same value for two or more
>   applications, they will all share the same ID — provided that they are
>   also signed by the same certificate. **Application with the same user ID
>   can access each other's data** and, if desired, run in the same process.

Comment: This worked for me! Also was helpful for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16269956/two-app-with-shared-userid

Answer (score 0):

[internal storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) has/had the possibility to set a flag for world readable/writeable, but it is deprecated since api level 17.

another solution is to use [content providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) which contains your data you want to share. via a content resolver you are able to access these data.