# flutter: security issue - exported activity

Tags: android, flutter, security, android-activity

Security vendor has reported a VAPT issue with my flutter app. [CWE-926: Improper Export of Android Application Components](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/926.html). The flutter app by default has only one main-activity.

```
<application
    android:label="MyApp"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:fullBackupContent="false">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
</application>
```

There are 2 recommendations to fix this issue as per CWE page

- Add `android:exportable="false"`

The main activity is exportable. If I add `android:exportable="false"` to the main activity, I am not able to run the app. it ends with error, when I try to run it on emulator.

- Use `android:protectionLevel="signature"`

I am new to android development. I tried to [create new permission and use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45342782/android-signature-level-permission-among-multiple-apps) for application, but again getting error as `permission denied`.

I am clueless as to how to solve this issue? As I understand, MainActivity has to be exportable. So not sure how to solve this.

Comment: I am currently facing the same issue as you, as our Flutter App shall set the exported flag to false. But when I do this I got some weird behavior on different devices and different Android versions. On some Android versions the app will not start after tapping on the app icon (it shows a notification that the app is not installed) and on others it works like a charm. I don't find any information about Flutter and the exported Flag but I would like to understand if it can be set to false or not or if there are other opportunities.